# Report subscription not executing on scheduled date?

Tags: reporting-services

There is report subscription added to send report on 1st of every month. but report is running on 3rd of every month and user needs only on 1st.  I have tested everything n and all looks fine. can anyone suggest me any reason for this?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. Can you please post what the job you use to schedule the report looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a starting point on what your subscriptions are set to.

```
SELECT RS.[ScheduleID]
      , C.Name
      ,[ReportID]
      ,RS.[SubscriptionID]
      ,[ReportAction]
      ,S.LastRunTime
      , SC.*
  FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ReportSchedule] RS
  JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog C on RS.ReportID = C.ItemID
  JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj on Cast(RS.ScheduleID as varchar(500)) = cast(sj.name as varchar(500))
  JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions S ON RS.SubscriptionID = S.SubscriptionID
  JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Schedule SC ON RS.ScheduleID = SC.ScheduleID
```